# Strange React Native Web Error After Update

Tags: create-react-app, eslint, react-native-web

We are using `react-native-web` to build a project and after updating all of our dependencies this morning we’re getting the following error in the console for most of the components in the project:
`Cannot read property ‘forEach' of undefined`

[image]

However, if we roll back the `package.json` the following error is emitted on every `mousemove` event:

[image]

Seemingly related to `react-native-web` and the `ResponserEventPlugin` specifically - but rolling back the rnw version doesn’t fix the issue either.

Everything was in complete working order until we ran `ncu -u` earlier today.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: We're experiencing the same issue.  Will post here if a solution is found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the maintainer just pushed a fix for the issue. Long story short, it was related to `react-dom`.

Release: https://github.com/facebook/react/releases/tag/v16.10.2